# No Method Found Error

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a basic spring mvc 3.0 application. But when i launch my server, i get the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:830)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 6):

You have two libraries which are incompatible because of different versions.

On one hand you have `spring-beans.jar` in Version 3.0.5 (or some other 3.0.x). -- This jar contains `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata` with an two parameter constructor `public InjectionMetadata(Class targetClass, Collection<InjectedElement> elements)`.
And this is the only one constructor of that class.

On the other hand you have `spring-orm.jar`, I do not know its version but I guess something like 2.0.x or 3.1.x. This contains a class `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which try to create an instance of `InjectionMetadata` with an one parameter constructor.

And this result in this

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.(Ljava/lang/Class;)V

The solution is simple: make sure that `spring-beans.jar` and `spring-orm.jar` (as well as every other spring jar) is of the same version.

Answer (score 1):

Do a search including archives (.jar files) (easy with Total Commander for example) on your classpath for files containing `InjectionMetadata.class`. Errors like this usually happen when there is a different version of the class loaded runtime then used/seen by your favourite IDE when you edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

Review libraries version. You can be using a old spring-beans version and a newer spring-core one, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can make all jars consistent using BOM dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: make sure that spring-beans.jar and spring-orm.jar (as well as every other spring jar) is of the same version.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).